# clang-format not enforcing SpacesBeforeTrailingComments for /* comment */

Tags: clang-format

I'm using **clang-format** to automatically format my C code, and I'm having an issue with the `SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2` option.

It seems that clang-format is not enforcing spaces before trailing comments when they are written in the `/* comment */` style. Comment style `// comment` works as expected.

Here is an example:

```
# .clang-format style file
...
SpacesBeforeTrailingComments: 2
```

```
int x;  // comment enforced to SpacesBeforeTrailingComments == 2
int y; /* comment enforced to SpacesBeforeTrailingComments == 1 */
```

Comment: SpacesBefore**Trailing**Comments - the option name is self-documented. Also the manual: *The number of spaces before trailing line comments (// - comments).*

Comment: @273K Thank you! The documentation states clearly also "...This does not affect trailing block comments (/* - comments)..."
But is there a way to force enable it on `/*` comemnts